# Nested inner join & sub-select in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I have this SQL in Access, but it is giving me an error. I've tried moving the parenthesis around but it hasn't resolved the issue.

```
SELECT
    a.title, a.id, a.name, l.user, l.time 
FROM
    Reports a
INNER JOIN (
    AuditLog AS l ON a.id = l.id
INNER JOIN (
(
    SELECT min(time) Mintime, id
    from AuditLog
    GROUP BY id
) AS t )
  ON l.id = t.id
  AND l.time = t.mintime )
WHERE
    a.NAME LIKE 'something*'
    AND a.ACTIVE='Y'
```

How can I resolve the syntax errors I'm getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This piece of your query should definitely create a problem:

```
SELECT min(time) Mintime, id
```

If you intend to alias the field expression `min(time)` as `Mintime`, you *must* use the `AS` keyword.  You don't need `AS` for a table alias but you do for a field alias:

```
SELECT min(time) AS Mintime, id
```

It seems `time` is a field in your `AuditLog` table.  In that case enclose its name in square brackets to distinguish it from the `Time()` function:

```
SELECT min([time]) AS Mintime, id
```

As for the parentheses, you should use Access' query designer to set up your joins if possible.  It will guarantee your query includes the parentheses the db engine demands and will position them correctly.

If that's not an option, give this untested version a try:

```
SELECT
    a.title, a.id, a.name, l.user, l.time 
FROM
    (Reports a
    INNER JOIN AuditLog AS l
    ON a.id = l.id)
    INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT min([time]) AS Mintime, id
            from AuditLog
            GROUP BY id
        ) AS t
    ON
            l.id = t.id
        AND l.time = t.mintime
WHERE
        a.NAME LIKE 'something*'
    AND a.ACTIVE='Y'
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't need parenthesis unless you have `or` conditions.  Try this in Access and see if it works:

```
SELECT
    a.title, a.id, a.name, l.user, l.time 
FROM
    (Reports a INNER JOIN AuditLog AS l ON a.id = l.id) INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT min(time) as Mintime, id
        from AuditLog
        GROUP BY id
    ) AS t ON l.id = t.id AND l.time = t.mintime
WHERE
    a.NAME LIKE 'something*'
    AND a.ACTIVE='Y'
```

I haven't done sub-queries in Access though, so it will be interesting to see if it reports an error next to the open parenthesis of the sub-query.

Comment: I tried that and got an error `Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '(a.id = l.id) INNER JOIN .........`

Comment: Same thing: `Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'a.id = l.id INNER JOIN ...........`

Comment: Been doing queries in Access and MSSQLServer for years -- nothing looks wrong..., Although, I haven't dong sub-queries like this in Access, so that may be what it is complaining about.  I'll do a quick test and let you know what I find.

Comment: I came from TSQL and I think this worked, but the syntax is a bit different in Access I think. I believe the documentation mentioned needed parenthesis after the joins.

Comment: I got my SQL to work by carefully placing the `()` around the joined tables, and then `INNER JOIN` them to the sub-query.  See the edited example.